# Is it possible to use 2 (or 3) different grey scaled images as input in a convolutional neural network (CNN) instead of a unique colored one?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, channel

Using a CNN approach for a regression task i wonder if i can use 2 (or 3) differents grey scaled images (2 or 3 images with the same shape x * y * 1, giving separate informations), for each of 2 or 3 channels of a given input layer, instead of for example one RGB image occupying the 3 channels.

I didn't find any similar question on the web or in my books about this kind of image setting.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you can't, what do you want to achieve with this though?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, i want to use slices of  2 B&W waveformes representing 2 different types of informations for my regression task. I could also use "manual" features extraction (mean, skew,kurtosis informations...) prior i suppose. For now i didn't find example of CNN using a different B&W information source for each channel of an input layer, so i wondered if i was on the wrong path!